# Hudson, Svn & notification sent after a commit

Tags: svn, hudson

HI,
We are currently using  Hudson with the plugin SVN. Every error during the maven build implies a email sending to the developpers.

We would like to send an email or better a jabber message (we are all using it) to all developpers that a commit was just done (so they may have to update)

Any solution ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards

Comment: You might get better answers if you accepted some previous answers given to you in your other questions. Just use the checkmark symbol next to the one that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

How about sending notification from SVN, not Hudson?

Comment: Absolutely! You should send commit notifications is through a Subversion commit hook. You have much more flexibility on who / what to send (e.g. you can include the diffs).

Comment: The question is a bit disjointed, but I think the desire is to send an email/jabber notification only on error.  Otherwise, I'm not sure why this sentence is in the question: 'Every error during the maven build implies a email sending to the developers.'

Answer (score 1):

The [Jabber plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Jabber+Plugin) has the ability to send notifications on failure.  Those notifications can go only to the SCM contributers of that build.

Hudson's built-in email system also has the ability to send only to the contributors when there is a failure.   Have you looked at the UI and built-in help?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Konrad. You should use SVN commit hook. But if you really want to go with Hudson, have a look at the [Email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin). I haven't tested it yet, but was toying with the idea when switching from CC to send builds out, when build was successful.